# Bad HD video deinterlacing processing

Tags: video, mplayer, unity

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with Unity. My system configuration is:

```
CPU: Core 2 Quad Q6600 (2.4 GHz)
RAM: 8192 Mb DDR2 Kingston
Video: Palit GeForce GTX 260 216 SP, and my screen resolution is 1680x1050.
```

I also have Window 7 Ulitimate installed, and I can see the same files in Media Player Classic without any horizontal lines.

I've installed vdpau driver, NVIDIA drivers 304.51, and MPlayer 2 (within SMPlayer). I've disabled `Sync to VBlank` option in CCSM (because in other way, by default, MPlayer process use about 50-60 percents of my processor load), tried to swich between different deinterlace options in SMPlayer, used `-vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau` parameters for MPlayer, switched to `Ubuntu 2D`, but, finally, have no results.

Any suggestions? How must I to set up MPlayer?

Comment: Please try VLC player and it's "deinterlace","deinterlace mode" and other post-processing options.

Comment: Do you have gstreamer plugins installed? I believe that this allows hardware decoding of media.

Comment: Just to try to isolate the problem, try use mplayer from the command line, don't use vdpau and try to use `-vf yadif` for the deinterlacing. What is the result that you get?